# Using an object as a lookup table: Values dont update after first call

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I'm trying to implement a variable system for my html web pages. That's why I wrote a function that will take some string, search it for variables, replace them with their corresponding value and the give the new string back:

```
//Finish HTML files by replacing variables
handlers.insertVariables = function(file, callback){
  //Load variables
  let variables = require('./variables.js');
  console.log(variables) //For debugging only
  //Loop through all possible variables and replace
  for(let key in variables){
    if(variables.hasOwnProperty(key)){
      let find = '{' + key + '}';
      let replace = variables[key];

      file = file.split(find).join(replace)
      //file = file.replace('{' + key + '}', variables[key])
    }
  }

  //Callback the new file
  callback(false, file);

};
```

This part works without issues. Its also able to replace multiple instances of the same variable. The problem is now the external variables.js file. I made an external file for these as I will probably a few dozens of these in the future. This is the variable.js file:

```
//Container with all variables
let variables = {
  'landing_videoID': global.newestVideo.id,
  'landing_time': new Date(Date.now()).toUTCString()
};

//Export the variables
module.exports = variables;
```

When the handlers.insertVariables function gets called for the first time, it will receive the up-to-date values. But these then are not changing anymore. Is there something that I'm doing wrong, or is my attempt just bs in general?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module is cached after first `require`. One way to solve this problem is to export as function and call it every time as follows:

So, refactor `variable.js` as follows:

```
//Container with all variables
function getValues()
  return {
    'landing_videoID': global.newestVideo.id,
    'landing_time': new Date(Date.now()).toUTCString()
  };
}

//Export the variables
module.exports = getValues;
```

Then, `require` `variable.js` like this:

```
//Load variables
  let variables = require('./variables.js')();
```